# garbage value return by struct function

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{

    char sharePath[100];
    char logPath[100];
    char motd[100];

}pathName_t;

void readConfig(const char *config){ 
    FILE *fp = fopen(config, "r");
    pathName_t pathpath;
    int line = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int c;
    c = getc(fp);

    while( c != EOF){

    if( c != '\n' ){  //if c not equal to new line, loop through the entire line
       if( line == 0 ){  //line = 0
       pathpath.sharePath[index] = c;
          }else if( line == 1 ){  //line = 1
          pathpath.logPath[index] = c;
             }else{  //line = 2
             pathpath.motd[index] = c;
             }
             index++;
    }else{  //if c equal to new line, replace \0 from \n to the end of string
       if( line == 0 ){  //line = 0
       pathpath.sharePath[index] = '\0';
          }else if( line == 1 ){  //line = 1
          pathpath.logPath[index] = '\0';
             }else{  //line = 2
             pathpath.motd[index] = '\0';
             }
        index = 0;
        line++;
    }  // else close
    c = getc(fp);
}  //while loop close
    fclose(fp);
}  //readConfig() close



int main(){

    pathName_t pathName;
    readConfig("settings.config");
    printf("%s", pathName.motd);
    printf("%s",pathName.sharePath);
}
```

**This is the result i get: �z���**

I'm intended to create a function to read and retrieve path name store in   this file in multiple line, end up the struct compiled but the result seems goes wrong.. Or any of you have suggestion is there any other method to read contents from a file and have a multiple return value?

Comment: You aren't returning anything to your main function. So the garbage values are whatever was already on main's stack.

Comment: `prog.c:15:16: error: variable ‘pathpath’ set but not used`

Comment: `pathName` is local to `main`.  It won't magically become populated just because you call a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does nothing. You do not pass pointer to your local variable or assign it with return value and you print a random garbage which was on the stack